# How to get unique values and counts after string split in each cell of a table

Tags: r, stringr

I have a datframe called df. I want to string split the values in a, b, and c columns based on `,` and get the columns of unique elements for each column and counts for those unique elements as shown in the result below. How can we get this done in R? Thanks for your help.

```
a <- c("cat, cat, dog", "dog")
b<- c("cat")
c<- c("dog, dog", "cat")

df <- data.frame(position= c("1","2"),a, b, c, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Result I want:

```
position    a_uniq  b_uniq  c_uniq  a_uniq_counts   b_uniq_counts   c_uniq_counts
1           cat,dog cat     dog     2               1               1
2           dog     cat     cat     1               1               1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you a solution using data.table:

```
unique_counts <- function(str){
return(uniqueN(unlist(strsplit(gsub(" ", "" ,str), ","))))
}

unique_strings <- function(str){
  return(paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(gsub(" ", "" ,str), ","))), collapse=","))
}

a <- c("cat, cat, dog", "dog")
b<- c("cat")
c<- c("dog, dog", "cat")


df <- data.frame(position= c("1","2"),a, b, c, stringsAsFactors = F)
df <- as.data.table(df)
for (i in colnames(df)[2:length(colnames(df))]){
  df[ , eval(paste0(i,"_uniq")):=mapply(unique_strings, get(i))]
  df[ , eval(paste0(i,"_uniq_counts")):=mapply(unique_counts, get(i))]
  df[ , eval(i):=NULL]
}
```

Best!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  Using `mutate_at`, split the string at the delimiter `,`, and get the unique counts with `uniqueN`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
      mutate_at(vars(a:c), funs(uniq_counts = strsplit(., ", ") %>%
                  map_int(n_distinct)))
#  position             a   b        c a_uniq_counts b_uniq_counts c_uniq_counts
#1        1 cat, cat, dog cat dog, dog             2             1             1
#2        2           dog cat      cat             1             1             1
```